# How to calculate the thermal expansion of hollow cylinder

Tags: thermal-expansion

Outer diameter = 256 mm

Inner diameter = 230 mm

The material is Aluminum

Temperature ranges from 23 °C to 200 °C.

Solid cylinder formula is, d<sub>1</sub>=d<sub>0</sub>(dt*α+1).

Where, α = 15.2 ×10<sup>-6</sup> /K (approx)

How to consider when the cylinder is hollow?

Comment: You should show some effort towards a solution.

Comment: I have calculated for solid cylinder, I dont know how to consider, when it is hollow. And I am interested to know, how much expansion is happening in inner diameter

Comment: if you have considered for a solid cylinder, I ask: what is its height after thermal expansion and why?  Think about what is happening in this even, unloaded thermal expansion.  It is certainly different from reality where gradients and forces are everywhere.

Comment: A hollow tube (or cylinder) of same material and same dimensions as a solid object will expand exactly equally. They will both grow the same amount. The hole's diameter will also increase in proportion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the cylinder wall is thin an approximate method to calculate the expansion of circumference is:

Let's call the initial circumference, $C_0=2\pi r_0=2\pi* 230mm .$

The change in diameter due to temperature is  $$ \ d_c=c_1 - c_0= 2 π r_0 \Delta t *α \quad\\ \rightarrow dc = 2 π r_1 - 2 π r_0 = 2 π r_0 \Delta t* α  $$.

- $\alpha=$ linear expansion coefficient.

[source](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thin-circular-ring-radius-temperature-change-d_1612.html)